# Handling generic properties via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

If I have the following wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string[] Metadata { get;set;
}
```

and another class then exposes that value without generics:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public object WrappedData { get;set };
}
```

, how can I get at the original unwrapped data?

I can test for it, using something like:

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Wrapper<>))
{
    dynamic originalValue = someOtherClass.WrappedData;
}
```

but I can't then call the `.Data` property on `originalValue`, getting a `RuntimeBinderException`.

---

**Update**

A little more context might help. I am working on a WebAPI where I am wanting to implement HATEOAS. So my wrapper class is containing the data that will be returned plus metadata, and I am writing an action filter that will unwrap the data, returning it in the response body, and put the metadata into response headers. The action filter is currently implemented as follows:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (objectContent != null)
        {
        var type = objectContent.ObjectType;
        var formatter = actionExecutedContext
            .ActionContext
            .ControllerContext
            .Configuration
            .Formatters
            .First(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes
                .Contains(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(actionExecutedContext
                    .Response
                    .Content
                    .Headers
                    .ContentType
                    .MediaType)));

            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Wrapper<>))
            {
                dynamic value = objectContent.Value;
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(value.Data.GetType(), value.Data, formatter);
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Obviously not all my API endpoints currently wrap their data, so if the response is not returning a `Wrapper<T>` instance, I want to exit the action filter without modifying the response. If it is, then pull out the value of `.Data` and rewrite the response body with it.

Comment: What does `WrapperData` contain? If it only contains the value of `Wrapper<T>.Data` it's clear. If it contains the whole wrapper we should look for problem on initialization side.

Comment: What does contain `type` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the posted code what `objectContent.ObjectType` is, so I would modify the code to check the actual value:

```
object value = objectContent.Value;
if (value != null && value.GetType().IsGenericType && value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Wrapper<>))
{
    object data = ((dynamic)value).Data;
    actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(data.GetType(), data, formatter);
}
```

But you can avoid reflection and dynamic calls and make your life much easier if you backup your generic class with a non generic interface. For instance

```
public interface IWrapper
{
    object Data { get; }
    string[] Metadata { get; }
}

public class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    object IWrapper.Data { get { return Data; } }
    public string[] Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do simple

```
var wrapper = objectContent.Value as IWrapper;
if (wrapper != null)
{
    actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(wrapper.Data.GetType(), wrapper.Data, formatter);
}
```

Comment: SImple is best :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Wrapper<T>
        {
            public T Data { get; set; }
            public string[] Metadata
            {
                get; set;
            }

        }

        public class SomeOtherClass
        {
            public object WrappedData { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wrappedData = new Wrapper<int> { Data = 3 };
            var someObject = new SomeOtherClass { WrappedData = wrappedData };

            dynamic d = someObject.WrappedData;
            Console.WriteLine(d.Data);

        }
    }
}
```

So, It isn't clear what your problem is!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you added the type to your wrapper?

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public Type MyType{get;set;}
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string[] Metadata { get;set;}

    public Wrapper(T data){
      MyType = data.GetType();
      Data = data; 
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the MyType property though? It's just as hard to access as the Data property. How can I instantiate or cast my instance of SomeOtherClass.WrappedData to Wrapper<T>?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question. Sorry, I misread your original post a little. Would it make sense to ask why you need to do this trick btw? Feels a little odd with boxing values in these days of SOLID design - I'm curious, and you probably have a perfectly good reason for doing so :)

Comment: Have you looked at the following?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883957.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes I had; however, I wanted to be able to unwrap the original data, and return the metadata in response headers, rather than create an envelope in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear exactly what you are trying to do:

```
object obj = new Wrapper<SomeOtherClass> { Data = new SomeOtherClass { WrappedData = "Hello" } };
Type type = obj.GetType();

if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Wrapper<>))
{
    dynamic data = ((dynamic)obj).Data;
    dynamic wrappedData = data.WrappedData;
}
```

Note that there is no guarantee that there is a `WrappedData` property inside the `Data` property: `WrappedData` is a property of `SomeOtherClass`, but for example `obj` could be:

```
object obj = new Wrapper<string> { Data = "Hello" };
```